# Is it possible to write a generic trigger for all tables in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, trigger, listener, event-notification

I want to listen to every transaction that is recorded in the database And I noticed that there is a concept in Postgres under the title **LISTEN** and **NOTIFY** (Of course, I am not sure that this is the right way)

Now I want to write a trigger that sends a notification to the channel when any operation occurs in any table

Is it possible?

My way is right?

thanks

[Postgres TRIGGER to call NOTIFY with a JSON payload](https://gist.github.com/goliatone/5fbeb1912e5937e8e3cf94618be9bebf)

Comment: Even if it's possible, it's probably not the right thing to do. Perhaps you're looking for an [audit solution](https://www.pgaudit.org/)? What is it that you're trying to achieve by "listening for every transaction"?

Comment: I want to write a service like Debezium
https://debezium.io/

Do you think I should use this?

https://datacater.io/blog/2021-09-02/postgresql-cdc-complete-guide.html#cdc-logical-replication

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create an event trigger on ddl_command_end, then inside that event trigger create a regular trigger when a "CREATE TABLE" statement is executed, so you can automatically keep track of all newly created tables.